# Não estou exibindo o múltiplo corretamente

Tags: c, algoritmo

Desenvolvi um algoritmo que deve exibir o maior múltiplo entre `num1 <= num2`. Usei como exemplo 7 e 50 e funcionou corretamente, exibindo o valor 49, mas ao enviar para avaliação existe uma inconsistência que não estou reconhecendo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int num1, num2, i, temp, resultado;

  scanf("%i", & num1);
  scanf("%i", & num2);

  if (num1 > num2) {
    temp = num1;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = temp;
  }

  for (i = num1; i <= num2; i++) {
    if (num1 % i == 0) {
      resultado = num1 * i;
    }
  }
  if (resultado <= num2) {
    printf("%i\n", resultado);
  } else {
    printf("sem multiplos menores que %i", num2);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"mas ao enviar para avaliação existe uma inconsistência que não estou reconhecendo"* como assim inconsistência, o que quer dizer?

Comment: Olá, vou mostrar enviar o link da questão, http://thehuxley.com/problem/36.
As dicas são:
Você realmente está encontrando o maior? Será que não existe outro número ainda maior?
Lembre de tentar até o último número, incluindo ele.

Comment: precisa apenas explicar o que quer dizer com inconsistência

Comment: O site afirma que não estou encontrando o maior múltiplo e nem incluindo o num2

Comment: @MauroAlmeida o exemplo dado no site com a entrada e saída são esses, http://thehuxley.com/problem/36

Comment: Sobre o entendimento da questão: em minha opinião a questão não pede que você inverta os números caso num2 < num1, neste caso a resposta seria "sem multiplos menores que N". Em termos de lógica: como é para encontrar o maior múltiplo eu começaria o teste em N e iria decrementando até encontrar o primeiro múltiplo, ou eventualmente chegar a M, em um laço while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O enunciado não é tão claro, então eu nem me preocuparia muito se isto está certo, apenas focar no resultado, o que daria até pra trapacear já que nem dá para saber exatamente [o que o desafio pede](http://thehuxley.com/problem/36) por ambiguidade do texto. Lá nada pede para fazer com que o limite seja sempre o maior valor digitado e acho que isto é um erro do algoritmo, mas eu deixei assim. E talvez o que ele queira seja o quadrado do menor número, porque aí faria sentido não ter um valor válido, se for um múltiplo simples então qualquer número menor é válido, só não pode ser igual, a não ser que o enunciado queira dizer que tem que ser um número que tenha sido multiplicado por pelo menos 2, enfim, vamos fazer de conta que isso só pra dar o resultado (eu pularia exercício mal feito ou trapacearia só dando 49 como resultado). Pra calcular múltiplo é só usar matemática e não precisa de complicações como estava no algoritmo. Pense tudo matematicamente, é muito mais simples, só quando a matemática não resolve é que deve pensar em algoritmo complexo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    if (num1 > num2) {
        int temp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
    }
    int multiplo = (num2 / num1) * num1;
    if (multiplo <= num2) printf("%d\n", multiplo);
    else printf("sem multiplos menores que %d", num2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/74TT56). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/GreatestMultiple). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/GreatestMultiple.c).

Comment: Mas o objetivo não é mostrar o maior múltiplo do primeiro numero que seja inferior ao segundo numero ? Isso é o que eu leio no enunciado, e que faz sentido para o exemplo demonstrado, ou seja, o maior múltiplo de 7 que seja inferior ou igual a 50, por isso resulta em 49.

Comment: Como eu disse o enunciado é ambíguo. Mesmo que fosse diferente daria pra fazer com matemática sem laços, claro depende do quanto fosse diferente, mas aí seria diferente demais.

Answer (score 1):

Mano na real o enunciado ta claro tem 2 int
o primeiro eh o numero que tu precisa achar o multiplo, o segundo eh o limitador do multiplo, ou seja tu tem que achar o maior multiplo e ele tem que ser menor ou igual ao numero 2

entao tu nao precisa deternimar o maior numero

```
    if (num1 > num2) {
        int temp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
    }
```

nao precisa disso, nao ta pedindo pra vc achar o maior entre os dois

uma solucao seria:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int num, less_than, multiple, i;
    scanf("%d%d", &num, &less_than);

    multiple = 0;
    i = 0;
    for (i = less_than; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((i % num) == 0) {
            multiple = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (multiple > 0) {
        printf("%d", multiple);
    } else {
        printf("sem multiplos menores que %i", less_than);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ele acha o valor `49`quando `num1 == 1`, isto é, na primeira iteração.
No site que você referenciou: [THEHUXLEY](http://thehuxley.com/problem/36) não requisita que seja necessário `num1 <= num2`, como apontou @Adir Kuhn

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int num1, num2, maior = -1;

  scanf("%d", &num1);
  scanf("%d", &num2);
  for(int i=1; i*num1 <= num2; i++){
     maior=i*num1;
  }
  if (maior != -1) {
    printf("%d\n", maior);
  } else {
    printf("sem multiplos menores que %d", num2);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Isso é mais questão de algoritmo do que C, pois em C poderíamos obter o valor usando o fato de que a divisão de inteiros tem como resultado um número inteiro, e poderíamos usar, após verificar que 0 < num1 < num2 :

```
printf("Numero: %d.\n", (num2/num1) * num1);
```

Portanto, não são equivalentes `(num2/num1) * num1` e `num2`.